# left sidebar toggle menu stops working when i add a wrapper div in my templates body

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

i am try to create a Single-Page application using vali-admin template in Laravel. The template works fine but when i create a wrapper 'div' just beneath the body, the sidebar toggle stops working. i need the wrapper 'div' to render the '#app' from vue components.

**this is a snippet from the template**

```
  <body class="app sidebar-mini">
  </body>
```

**This is what i want to accomplish**

```
    <body>
        <div id="app"  class="app sidebar-mini">
      </div>
     </body>
```

This is the link to vali admin template
http://demo.cssmoban.com/cssthemes4/tpez_6_vf/dist/index.html

Comment: Why you copying `sidebar-mini` class to newly created div. You can start the Vue app in anywhere of your code. But you should keep the `app` & `sidebar-mini` class in the body tag. because the styles and javascript functions are working based on these classes and body tags. You can check the working in the `main.js` file in your project. If you want to change this normal working process you need to change this `main.js` and styles related to the sidebar

Comment: @JithinVijayan initially, i maintained sidebar-mini in the body and created a new div then add the #app id but still got the same problem

Comment: can you please post the code somewhere and comment the link or gimme the repository link.

Comment: this is the template  "https://github.com/pratikborsadiya/vali-admin".  i just want to add <div id="app></div> just beneath the body tag then use it to render <router-view></router-view>

Comment: Oh, this is the template repository. I think you are using the Laravel framework can you please share your project repository or code. Investing time in this template repository is really bad idea. So please share your code.

Comment: @JithinVijayan this is my project link "https://github.com/ike-eons/isaac-project"  and this is where the problem is originating "https://github.com/ike-eons/isaac-project/blob/master/resources/views/admin/app.blade.php"  i add the  <div id="app">

Comment: After a few checking, I couldn't find any mistakes in this sidebar and header files. Maybe some javascript errors pausing this sidebar functionality. So before concentrating on this issue please check your browser console.

Comment: thanks @JithinVijayan i have change the template